# Jolt converter keep key

Tags: java, json, jolt

Let say I have an input

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

with this spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": "wrapper.a",
      "b": "wrapper.b"
    }
  }
]
```

The output is

```json
{
  "wrapper" : {
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2
  }
}
```

But i think maybe there is another shorter way to do the same thing, such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "wrapper.[WHATEVER HERE, NEED HELP FROM YOU GUYS]"
    }
  }
]
```

Could you guys help to give the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can replace with the operators **`"*"`** to match key names of all attributes and **`"&"`** to substitute corresponding values for those attributes at the current level(*within the current object*) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "wrapper.&"
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]